# adding res directories do not show up in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I added `res directories` in android studio for my android project. I added them using the IDE as well as manually with `mkdir res_dir`. However, they do not show up on the project tree. I want to view them on the tree so I know for sure they are in the project rather than `ls` every time to check. I tried restarting my IDE but this problem is still there

[image]

[image]

I added the `res directories`: drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xdpi but I do not see them on the tree. How can I make these appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some files into the folders, this will show up the folders inside drawable.

Comment: I added files to my drawable-xhdpi directory. However according to the project tree it is if I added to drawable. https://postimg.org/image/whbupjy5d/  https://postimg.org/image/ycnbvgo8h/

Comment: This is just the way it works. Do you see the (xhdpi) in the brackets? That tells you that it's in that particular folder, it's just that android presents it to you in this way.